# How to properly decode a JSON string encoded using Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, razor

I am encoding some model data into a html element like this:

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

The json string returned looks like this:

```
{"TestList":[{"FrequencyType":"1X","GCDs":"585.6","Identifier":"6144","SeqNo":9306,"SeqNoSpecified":true,"TSeqNo":8314,"TSeqNoSpecified":true,"TestDescr":"HBsAg"},{"FrequencyType":"1X","GCDs":"585.6","Identifier":"6124","SeqNo":9295,"SeqNoSpecified":true,"TSeqNo":8315,"TSeqNoSpecified":true,"TestDescr":"HCV Ab"},{"FrequencyType":"1X","GCDs":"585.3","Identifier":"6","SeqNo":9729,"SeqNoSpecified":true,"TSeqNo":8309,"TSeqNoSpecified":true,"TestDescr":"HD Monthly LS"}],"Frequency":[{"Key":"ANNUAL","Value":"Annually"},{"Key":"BIMONTH","Value":"Bi-Monthly"},{"Key":"BIWEEK","Value":"Bi-Weekly"},{"Key":"MON","Value":"Monthly"},{"Key":"1X","Value":"One Time"},{"Key":"QTR","Value":"Quarterly"},{"Key":"SMAN","Value":"Semi-Annual"},{"Key":"WEEK","Value":"Weekly"}]};
```

When I try to parse this using `JSON.parse`, I get an error:

```
arrayTestList = [];
var jsonTestList = $('#TestList').text();
jsonTestList = JSON.stringify(jsonTestList);
arrayTestList = JSON.parse(jsonTestList);
alert(arrayTestList.TestList[0]); // <===== this line is failing

Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined
```

How do I convert this `jsonTestList` string into a javascript array so that I can access elements of `arrayTestList` properly?

**Edit:**

Sorry, I forgot to mention my edit. Basically above javascript code is inside a Partial View 2. The code where I am json encoding the model is in another Partial View 1. From P V 2, I cannot access the model object of P V 1, so I am just dumping the contents into a `div` tag, so that I can access this list `TestList` element.

Comment: Note that using `Html.Raw` is dangerous. if your json object's fields aren't sanitized, you are open to XSS attacks. eg. set one of your `TestDescr` properties to "</div><script>alert('hacked')</script>" (assuming your json is written inside a div element). When this is outputted it will close your opening div element, and the browser will then interpret the following script tag as part of the html dom and run whatever is inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is now resolved.

I was getting an invalid character, but couldn't immediately recognize which character it was that was causing the problem. I found that my JSON string isn't valid because of the trailing semicolon that was output by the `Json.Encode` method. I validated the JSON string @ http://jsonlint.com.

Once I removed that semicolon, the json string is populated as a JavaScript array into `arrayTestList` object.

Now just this works, as mentioned in both the answers above, `JSON.stringify` is not needed.

```
var arrayTestList = [];
var jsonTestList = $('#TestList').text().replace(";","");
arrayTestList = JSON.parse(jsonTestList);
alert(arrayTestList.TestList[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try removing this line:

```
jsonTestList = JSON.stringify(jsonTestList);
```

`jsonTestList` is already a JSON string

Comment: I get `0x800a03f6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid character` if I remove the line containing the JSON.stringify.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `Json.Encode`? Also in your code, why are you writing redundant code first you are using `JSON.stringify` and the `JSON.parse` same object.

```
jsonTestList = JSON.stringify(jsonTestList);
arrayTestList = JSON.parse(jsonTestList);
```

As per my understanding just `Html.Raw` will work

In JavaScript

```
var jsonObject = @Html.Raw(Model.TestList); //Here you will get JavaScript Object
var jsonTestList =  jsonObject.TestList;
```

Comment: Using only Html.Raw gives me the type of the model object and not the data inside it.

Comment: @Animesh, OH! you have edited from `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.TestList));` to `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));`, Can you please tell us what exactly you want to achieve in JavaScript? Maybe there is a better way to achieve it.

Comment: I have edited the question for more clarity. Sorry about that.